# replacing elements in atoms in Prolog

Tags: dictionary, replace, prolog

I'm writing a prolog predicate which replace an element with another in a given atom. The predicate I wrote is like this:

```
replace_var(Expr0, Var, Val, Expr) :-
    Expr0 =.. Chars,
    chars_replaced(Chars, Rs),
    Expr =.. Rs.

chars_replaced(Chars, Rs) :-
    maplist(rep, Chars, Rs).

rep(Var,Val).
rep(C, C) :- dif(C,var).
```

The result I want it to return is something like:

```
-?replace_var(hello, l, w, X).
X = hewwo.
```

The problem is about the `rep()` predicate. I don't know how to write it or how to pass the `Val` and `Var` to the predicate.

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a atom? What about using lists of chars?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The format of the Expr0 has to be an atom. Or what do you mean by lists of chars? Can you be more specific? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong

```
Expr0 =.. Chars
```

you need instead

```
atom_chars(Expr0, Chars)
```

and this one really puzzle me

```
rep(Var,Val).
rep(C, C) :- dif(C,var).
```

what do you mean, specially the second one ?

anyway, the whole *could* be

```
replace_var(Expr0, Var, Val, Expr) :-
  atom_chars(Expr0, Cs),
  maplist(rep(Var, Val), Cs, Ts),
  atom_chars(Expr, Ts).

 rep(C, T, C, T).
 rep(_, _, C, C).
```

disclaimer: untested code

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful!!